# how to install packages for word2vec in R, windows 64-bit?

Tags: r, word2vec

I'm trying to install packages `wordVectors` and `rword2vec` from GitHub, but having issues.

Links:

1. https://github.com/bmschmidt/wordVectors
2. https://github.com/mukul13/rword2vec

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please include an example of what code you've tried, as well as what specific problems you've encountered? That way, it will be easier for people here to help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

1. Go to their github pages (eg https://github.com/bmschmidt/wordVectors)
2. Click 'Clone or Download' to download a .zip file
3. In RStudio, click on the packages tab in the bottop right-hand panel
4. Click 'Install'
5. Under Install From, select 'Package Archive/Zip'
6. Select the .zip file you just downloaded
7. Click open